# Android - Horizontal RecyclerView inside a ListView, Performing onitemClicListener

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, onitemclicklistener

I have a horizontal `RecyclerView` inside a `ListView`, and i need to catch the event onItemClickListener from the Listview. I'm targeting API15, and i tested on a emulator with Nougut also in my device Android Version 4.4.2.

the following code its the custom layout for the Listview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_prueba"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/tv_column_1"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view_item"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

When the application runs on my device, the event onItemClickListener from the listview works only over the textview. Over the recycler view items, i can't get the listview event.

This is mock Data on the list view

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RecyclerViews are probably eating the events.

Set clicklisteners on the individual views in the Recyclerviews.

Also you should probably use a RecyclerView instead of the ListView.

Comment: If I set individual listener to the horizontal recycler views, how would i know wich row I'm pressing?